# Should I exclude factors loaded by only one variable when computing factor score

Tags: factor-analysis

I'm writing a thesis on "Factor affecting students academic performance at second cycle institutions."

I used factor analysis to extract 20 factors from 63 variables that presumably influence academic performance in second cycle institutions.

Out of the 20 factors extracted three of these factors had only one variable each. My question: would it be appropriate if I compute factor scores for the remaining 17 factors and ignore the three because they were only loaded by one variable?

Comment: You may ignore (not to interpet, not to use) any number of the factors that you extracted. But that (closing your eyes) doesn't make them non-existent. Hardly loaded factors might be seen as artefacts or as real factors for which you haven't collected enough indicators to reveal them well. Typical approach is to try to extract less factors - will they be interpretable? It is often to recommended that factors should load at least 3 variables. 20 factors out of 63 variables (1/3) seems to me a bit large number, at least in social sciences.

Comment: Think of it this way: Why _would_ you exclude those factors? I can't think of a good reason.

Comment: Before deciding whether to use all the factors, I'd worry about a FA that extracts 20 factors, especially from only 63 variables.  Also, you say you want to use these factors to explain student performance. That sounds like regression. Partial least squares may serve you better.